# Gutenberg default value not saved in json

Tags: block-editor

When I set default values in my attributes for my gutenberg blocks, the values can be consumed on  the client, but it does not appear in the JSON data until I change the attribute with setAttributes.

Example:

```js
attributes: {
            infoButtonText: { type: 'string', default: 'I am default' },
        },
```

Edit function starts with:

```js
function Edit( props ) {
    const { attributes, setAttributes } = props;
    ....
```

Since we have a headless setup the save function just returns `null`.

If I `console.log(attributes.infoButtonText)` it will show me 'I am default', but without touching it and hitting the save button it is just `null` in the JSON.

What am I not understanding?

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see your edit and save functions?

Comment: @SallyCJ I cannot send you the whole thing because of confidential information, but I have updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry for not quite understanding the question.. but I've just revised my answer - does it now answer your question? But regarding this: "*without touching it and hitting the save button it is just null in the JSON*", how did the JSON data look like? Is it `{"infoButtonText":null}` or `{"infoButtonText":"null"}`, or is it that `attributes.infoButtonText` returned exactly a `null` (and not the *string* 'null')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I set default values in my attributes for my Gutenberg blocks,
> the values can be consumed on the client, but it does not appear in
> the JSON data until I change the attribute with `setAttributes`.

When we register a block *type* (think of it like a *post type*) which happens on each page load, the block type data (title, default attributes/values, etc.) are saved (in memory) via the block types [data source](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/data-core-blocks/) (namespaced `core/blocks`), and that data is available to the client for as long as the page is opened, hence that's why the values can be consumed on the client despite the default attribute values are not in that JSON data (which is persistent and part of the post content that's saved in the database).

Therefore it's actually normal for Gutenberg (or the block editor) to not save the default attribute values to the JSON data (in the [block's comment delimiter](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/architecture/key-concepts/)), because the block editor can always read the values from the block type data in the block types data source. And for example, via the browser console, you can try this:

```js
// Inspect the attributes for the core Image block TYPE.
wp.data.select( 'core/blocks' ).getBlockType( 'core/image' ).attributes
```

And you'd see that the returned data is always the same (e.g. `linkDestination` in the above example, has its default set to `none`) and always accessible throughout the entire page via `wp.data` ([see @wordpress/data](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-data/)).

So don't worry when the default values do not appear in the JSON data — and you should also know that if you input a value that's same as the default one, then it won't be saved to the JSON data. I.e. Only custom values are supposed to be saved there.

```js
// Let's assume your block type's name is my-plugin/foo-block, with the attribute
// named infoButtonText which defaults to 'I am default'.

setAttributes( { infoButtonText: 'I am NOT default' } ); // using custom value
// Result: <!-- wp:my-plugin/foo-block {"infoButtonText":"I am NOT default"} /-->

setAttributes( { infoButtonText: 'I am default' } );     // using default value
// Result: <!-- wp:my-plugin/foo-block /-->
// I.e. The infoButtonText is no longer in the JSON data.
// But attributes.infoButtonText would actually return 'I am default' - the default value.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification! I really needed this. Have a great day, take care!

Comment: I understand it from an implementation details perspective, but so if I’m wanting my block admin to show some default text and for that default text to render on the frontend, do i then need to hardcode it on in my render php as well? If that’s the case it’s kinda pointless as a default value and instead acts as a placeholder=“”

Comment: @JamesOr if an attribute is not present in the JSON string, then the editor will use the attribute's default value, if any. So if you have set it during registration, then there shouldn't be any necessity to hardcode it. Think of it like these 2 PHP arrays: `$defaults` and `$json_data`, where if `! isset( $json_data['attribute'] )`, then `$defaults['attribute']` will be used if it exists.